# How to parse this XML file in PHP?

Tags: php, xml

I am failing to understand the examples provided on most sites relating to this. I want to be able to get a users input for example "Month: 1", "ID: 1", "Date: 01-01-2017" which then display that exact one.

I can't figure out how to move through XML this is my current idea

`echo $xml->fullyear->month[$monthGET]->finances[$passID]->projection`

However this doesn't work. How can I get it to output using the user inputs, the inputs work however.

This is my current PHP file to read the data:

```
<?php
$xml=simplexml_load_file("XML1.xml") or die("Error: Cannot create object");

echo $_GET["SearchChoice"];
echo $_GET["IDsend"];
echo $_GET["DateSend"];

switch ($_GET["SearchChoice"])
{
  case "ID Search":
    $passID = intval($_GET["IDsend"]);
    if ($passID !== 0)
    {
        $passID = $passID - 1;
    }
    $attr = $xml->finances[$passID]->attributes();
    echo "Date: ";
    echo $attr['date'];
    echo "<br> Projection: ";
    echo $xml->finances[$passID]->projection . ",<br>Recommended Staff: ";
    echo $xml->finances[$passID]->recommendedStaff . ",<br>Staff Wages: ";
    echo $xml->finances[$passID]->staffWages . ",<br>Actual: ";
    echo $xml->finances[$passID]->actual . "<br>";
    break;
  case "Date Search":
     $passDate = strval($_GET["DateSend"]);
     $nodes = $xml->xpath("/year2017/finances[@date='". $passDate . "']");
     if  ($nodes)
         $nodes = array_shift($nodes);
     break;
  default:
    $nodes = NULL;
}

if  ($nodes)
{
    echo "Date: ";
    $attr = $nodes->attributes();
    echo $attr['date'];
    echo "<br> Projection: ";
    echo $nodes->projection . ",<br>Recommended Staff: ";
    echo $nodes->recommendedStaff . ",<br>Staff Wages: ";
    echo $nodes->staffWages . ",<br>Actual: ";
    echo $nodes->actual . "<br>";
}
?>
```

Here is the snippet of my XML file.

```
<fullyear>
<month value="1">
    <finances id="1" date="01-01-2017">
      <projection>414</projection>
      <recommendedStaff>20</recommendedStaff>
      <staffWages>100</staffWages>
      <actual>250</actual>
    </finances>
    <finances id="2" date="02-01-2017">
      <projection>124</projection>
      <recommendedStaff>8</recommendedStaff>
      <staffWages>150</staffWages>
      <actual>250</actual>
      </finances>
    <finances id="3" date="03-01-2017">
      <projection>687</projection>
      <recommendedStaff>20</recommendedStaff>
      <staffWages>150</staffWages>
      <actual>250</actual>
    </finances>
    <finances id="4" date="04-01-2017">
      <projection>587</projection>
      <recommendedStaff>15</recommendedStaff>
      <staffWages>150</staffWages>
      <actual>250</actual>
    </finances>
    <finances id="5" date="05-01-2017">
      <projection>124</projection>
      <recommendedStaff>5</recommendedStaff>
      <staffWages>150</staffWages>
      <actual>250</actual>
    </finances>
    <finances id="6" date="06-01-2017">
      <projection>874</projection>
      <recommendedStaff>22</recommendedStaff>
      <staffWages>150</staffWages>
      <actual>250</actual>
    </finances>
    <finances id="7" date="07-01-2017">
      <projection>574</projection>
      <recommendedStaff>18</recommendedStaff>
      <staffWages>150</staffWages>
      <actual>250</actual>
    </finances>
</month>
    <month value="2">
    <finances id="32" date="01-02-2017">
      <projection>101</projection>
      <recommendedStaff>10</recommendedStaff>
      <staffWages>101</staffWages>
      <actual>101</actual>
    </finances>
    <finances id="33" date="02-02-2017">
      <projection>101</projection>
      <recommendedStaff>10</recommendedStaff>
      <staffWages>101</staffWages>
      <actual>101</actual>
    </finances>
    <finances id="34" date="03-02-2017">
      <projection>101</projection>
      <recommendedStaff>10</recommendedStaff>
      <staffWages>101</staffWages>
      <actual>101</actual>
    </finances>
    <finances id="35" date="04-02-2017">
      <projection>101</projection>
      <recommendedStaff>10</recommendedStaff>
      <staffWages>101</staffWages>
      <actual>101</actual>
    </finances>
    <finances id="36" date="05-02-2017">
      <projection>101</projection>
      <recommendedStaff>10</recommendedStaff>
      <staffWages>101</staffWages>
      <actual>101</actual>
    </finances>
  </month>
</fullyear>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing few thing. like month in the `case "ID Search":` and not providing proper path in `xpath`.

Try below:

```
<?php
$xml=simplexml_load_file("XML1.xml") or die("Error: Cannot create object");

$_GET["SearchChoice"]="Date Search";
$_GET["IDsend"]=1;// these are just sample values
$_GET["DateSend"]="01-01-2017";
$month=1;
switch ($_GET["SearchChoice"])
{
    case "ID Search":
        $passID = intval($_GET["IDsend"]);
        if ($passID !== 0)
        {
            $passID = $passID - 1;
        }

        $attr = $xml->month[$month]->finances[$passID]->attributes();
        echo "Date: ";
        echo $attr['date'];
        echo "<br> Projection: ";
        echo $xml->month[$month]->finances[$passID]->projection . ",<br>Recommended Staff: ";
        echo $xml->month[$month]->finances[$passID]->recommendedStaff . ",<br>Staff Wages: ";
        echo $xml->month[$month]->finances[$passID]->staffWages . ",<br>Actual: ";
        echo $xml->month[$month]->finances[$passID]->actual . "<br>";
        break;
    case "Date Search":
        $passDate = strval($_GET["DateSend"]);
        $nodes = $xml->xpath("/fullyear/month/finances[@date='". $passDate . "']");
        if  ($nodes)
            $nodes = array_shift($nodes);
        break;
    default:
        $nodes = NULL;
}

if  ($nodes)
{
    echo "Date: ";
    $attr = $nodes->attributes();
    echo $attr['date'];
    echo "<br> Projection: ";
    echo $nodes->projection . ",<br>Recommended Staff: ";
    echo $nodes->recommendedStaff . ",<br>Staff Wages: ";
    echo $nodes->staffWages . ",<br>Actual: ";
    echo $nodes->actual . "<br>";
}
```

**OUTPUT FOR XPATH Date Search:**

```
Date: 01-01-2017
Projection: 414,
Recommended Staff: 20,
Staff Wages: 100,
Actual: 250
```

**OUTPUT FOR XPATH ID Search:**

```
Date: 01-02-2017
Projection: 101,
Recommended Staff: 10,
Staff Wages: 101,
Actual: 101
```

Comment: Thank you, I've been looking at the same piece of code for too long I realise I missed silly things. How would I use it with a user input, the same as the IDsend variable?

Comment: @AlexJenkinson yes and you need month input also.